# CKEDITOR READONLY enable other buttons

Tags: ckeditor

I have a problem.
When I make the editor 'readonly' some of the buttons (copy, preview, full screen) stay enabled.

- Normal
  [image]
- Select some text
  [image]

How I can enabled other buttons when I select the text? (for example enabled button 'BGColor')

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this
Look for selection event.

```
CKEDITOR.instances["textarea"].on( 'selectionChange', function( evt ) {
    // get desired command from ckeditor 
    var myCommand = this.getCommand( 'CKEDITOR_COMMAND_NAME' );
    var mySelection = null;
    // check if something is selected
    var mySelection = this.getSelection().getNative() || this.window.$.getSelection() || this.document.$.selection;
    if (!mySelection) {
    // if not stay disable
        myCommand.disable();
    } else {
   //if yes enable command
    myCommand.enable();
    }

});
```